# TikZ: bars width and size of plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

This is a followup on my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60473/tikz-plot-datapoints-with-bars). I have tried to plot my data and I see the following now.[image: current image of the plot]

Would it be possible to define the size of the area that is used for the plot? I have tried to change the size with scale but that just does what it says.

Is there also a way to use smaller bars? I'm trying to get nearly vertical lines (very narrow bars) stopping at 1 in my case.

This is the part of the data file I'm trying to get working.

```
0.000021 1
0.000723 1
0.000835 1
0.024507 1
0.024628 1
0.027483 1
0.027548 1
0.027702 1
0.027778 1
0.027916 1
```

Comment: In general, you should always post a minimal example to show what you've tried and what doesn't work. Also, take a look at the [pgfplots manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots). It's really detailed, so it might seem a bit overwhelming at first, but if you skim through it once you'll have a good feeling of the capabilities and how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

I think in this case it's better to use a `ycomb` plot, which uses lines instead of bars. Your data is so closely spaced that bars would always be too wide.

You can control the size of the plot using `width=<length>` or `height=<length`. If you set only one of the two options, the plot area will be scaled proportionally, if you set both at the same time you can change the aspect ratio.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.000021 1
0.000723 1
0.000835 1
0.024507 1
0.024628 1
0.027483 1
0.027548 1
0.027702 1
0.027778 1
0.027916 1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{annotations.csv}{\annotationstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ycomb, ymin=0,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    width=15cm, height=5cm
]
\addplot +[mark=none] table {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```